# ImageMagick gif background not moving with png overlays

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to change the background layer of a batch of png images to include a moving gif. I'm running on MacOs and imagemagick version 7.1.0-19.

There are two types of images I want to merge:

- Overlay static images A*.png
- Background image Moving#40.gif
  The background gif takes 120 frames.

So far I have managed to build the images and create GIFs. However the animated gifs are not moving. I have tried including delay and loop but this does nothing. The code is as follows:

```
magick mogrify -format gif -delay 10 -draw 'image Dst_Over 0,0 0,0 "Moving#40.gif"' A*.png -loop 0
```

I have been looking for days for similar use cases but have not found a solution,I just recently got into ImageMagick so advice is much appreciated.

any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Post your PNG and GIF.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to process them one at a time in a script loop, since one is a gif animation. Then you would use a `null:` separator and -layers composite. For example for one PNG.

Transparent PNG:

[image]

Animation:

[image]

```
magick logot.png null: \( glitter.gif -coalesce \) -gravity center -compose dstover -layers composite -layers optimize result1.gif
```

[image]

See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite

Alternately, you can use -draw, but in the reverse with the png inside -draw and the GIF after magick.

```
magick glitter.gif -gravity center -draw 'image Over 0,0 0,0 "logot.png"' -layers optimize result2.gif
```

[image]